# What does it mean to have an exception for no mode? (The number that occurs the most in an array)?

Tags: c++, algorithm

When the problem is executed it works correctly stating that the mode is 3. The professor asked for "The program should account for the “exception” that no “mode” occurs – no value in the array occurs more than once." The thing is I do not understand what it is being asked. I cannot wrap my head around starting such a thing.

```
void showArray(const int[], int); 
void showMode(int [], int);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int Size = 11; //size of the array
    int test[Size] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5}; //elements of the array

    cout << "The Numbers in the Array are: \n";
    showArray(test, Size); //displays the array in its original order

    showMode(test, Size);

    return 0;
}

void showArray(const int arr[], int Size) 
{
    for(int count = 0; count < Size; count++)
        cout << arr[count] << " ";
    cout << endl;

}

void showMode(int test[], int Size)
{
    int counter = 1;
    int max = 0;
    int mode = test[0];

    for(int pass = 0; pass < Size - 1; pass++)
    {
        if(test[pass] == test[pass + 1])

            {
                counter++;
                if(counter > max)
                {
                    max = counter;
                    mode = test[pass];
                }
            }
        else
            counter = 1;
    }
    cout << "The Mode of the Array is: " << mode << endl;
}
```

Comment: Given the data {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, there are no repeating values, so there is no mode.

Comment: and if there is no mode, handle it appropriately.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Or there's an eight way tie (clearly 5 occurs more often than 9)

Comment: I don't think that will give you the mode. It only works on the given data because the mode appear next to each other. I think you need to change the if statement. if (test[pass] == mode)

Comment: @user2970916: I think it is written for a sorted array.  He's missing the function to actually sort it, though.

Answer (score 3):

When testing software, you want to have test cases that take all the different branches.  Right now you've only demonstrated that the code works <strike>when there is a unique highest-frequency element</strike> for the given input array.

Your professor also wants you to test when the highest repetition count is not unique.

This is often called a corner case.

The professor's phrasing is unfortunate.  The word *exception* has a specific meaning in C++, and this is not it... unless your instructions are to actually throw an exception when the highest repetition count isn't unique.

Good additional test cases would be:

- Array of length zero

  ```
  {}
  ```
- Array of length one

  ```
  { 7 }
  ```
- 2-way tie for highest repetition count

  ```
  { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 }
  { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 }
  ```
- N-way tie for highest repetition count

  ```
  { 1, 3, 5, 4, 2 }
  ```
- Tie is broken by first element

  ```
  { 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 6, 9 }
  ```
- Tie is broken by last element

  ```
  { 6, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 6, 2 }
  ```
- Other element has longer "run"

  ```
  { 5, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 4, 5, 2, 6, 9 }
  ```

If your code gives right results for all these cases, you will have high confidence that it is right for *all* inputs.

Comment: Care to provide sample data for those cases?  THe "tie is broken" ones are slightly confusing.  I think I know what you mean, but I'm not certain.